# Determine whether given f is shortest path function

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I have the following question:
Let $G = (V,E)$ be a directed graph  with a weight function $w:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$, and let $s \in V$ be a vertex such that there is a path from $v$ to every other vertex, i.e $0\leq dist(s,v) < \infty$. Let $f\colon V \to \mathbb R$ a given function. Describe an algorithm that runs in $O(|V| + |E|)$ that determines wethter this given $f$ is the shortest path function from $s$, i.e $\forall v \in V :f(v)=dist(s,v)$.

What I thought about was to check for every $v \in V$  whether $f$ fulfill the two following demands:

1. $f(s)=0$
2. $f(v) \leq f(u) + w(uv)$ for all $u \in V$ and $uv \in E$

This runs in the proper complexity. I thought to prove it by showing that $f(v) \leq dist(s,v) \land f(v) \geq dist(u,v) \Rightarrow f(v) = dist(f,v)$

I proved that $f(v) \leq dist(s,v)$, but I am stuck at proving that $f(v) \geq dist(s,v)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your conditions are not enough. For example, the function $f(v) \equiv 0$ satisfies them, but is (usually) not the shortest distance function.

You need to strengthen your second condition.

Comment: Forget what I wrote. I need to think about it again.

Comment: That's unsatisfiable in many cases.

Comment: OK, I understand what my problem was, I need to change condition 2 to something like: $f(v) = min(f(u) + w(uv)$ for all  $u \in V $ and $uv \in E$  Because we need that $f(v)$ to actually be equal to one of the paths and not just lower than all of them. Thank you. I will try to prove it now.

Comment: Right, that would fix it.

Comment: I try to prove it, but I still facing the same problem - I can prove that $f(v) \leq dist(s,v)$ ,I only know that $f(v)$ is smaller than something, but I have no clue from what it's bigger than, can I have a clue about how to start it?

Comment: Keep trying, and eventually you'll get it.